# Limit for $\lim _{n \to \infty}(n+2)^{2}\sin\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinity

Can't prove the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty}(n+2)^{2}\sin\frac{1}{n}=\infty.$$
by definition it should start: Let $M>0$. There exists an $N>0$ for every $n>N$:
$$(n+2)^{2}\sin\frac{1}{n}>M.$$

Any hints about how to minimize the value up there ?
*I think It's not true to use $\sin x>-1$
**I need to prove it by definition of limit**

Comment: Do you know that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$?

Comment: yes man I know but I need to prove it by definition.
sorry if was not clear enough

Comment: @user1993748: As you can see in my answer the hint by Hagen von Eitzen is the key to the solution here. You should not reject any suggestion straightway. But I believe its bit difficult to figure out that this hint can be used in a proper manner for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well we need some technique here and its a fairly standard technique. We need to understand that if $x \in (0, \pi/2)$ then $$\dfrac{\sin x}{x} > \cos x = 1 - 2\sin^{2}(x/2) > 1 - 2(x/2)^{2} = 1 - \dfrac{x^{2}}{2}$$ Putting $x = 1/n$ we get $$n\sin(1/n) > 1 - \frac{1}{2n^{2}}$$ and hence $$(n + 2)^{2}\sin(1/n) > n^{2}\sin(1/n) > n\left(1 - \frac{1}{2n^{2}}\right) = n - \frac{1}{2n} > n - 1$$ Now I hope you can continue it from here.

**Update**: The inequalities I have started with are fundamental and provide a key step to the proof of $\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$. For the proof of such identities see [this blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/11/teach-yourself-limits-in-8-hours-part-4.html) (search for "Proof of Standard Limits" in the post). It is interesting to see how such simple inequalities can help in establishing limits only by using definition of limit.

Answer (score 3):

$$
  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(n+2)^2\sin\ \frac{1}{n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(n+2)\frac{\sin\ \frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n+2}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(n+2) =\infty$$ since $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\sin\ \frac{1}{n}}{ \frac{1}{n+2}} =1$$

Comment: How can use this in proving by definition ?

Comment: Benghorbal suggested hint.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$ {(n+2)^2}\sin\left( \frac{1}{n}\right) > M \implies {(n+2)^2}\left( \frac{1}{n}\right)>M,$$

since

$$ \sin\left( \frac{1}{n}\right) \leq \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: Unfortunately this the REVERSE implication one needs. Upvoters: why the upvote?

Comment: This is the reverse implication so it wont help us in this direction sp I managed to solve this by using the fact that  lim n*sin(1/n) =1 for every epsilon we choose so : n*sin(1/n)>1/3 for example ...

Answer (score 1):

Let us write it as

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(\frac{1}{x}+2)^{2}\sin[x]$$
which is the continuous version of the problem with $x=\frac{1}{n}$. We expand $\sin[x]$ by
$$x-\frac{x^{3}}{6}+\frac{x^{5}}{120}\cdots$$
The left hand side is $2+\frac{1}{x^{2}}+2\frac{1}{x}$. We know $2\sin[x]$ and $2\frac{\sin[x]}{x}$ is bounded. But from the above expression it is clear that $\frac{\sin[x]}{x^{2}}$ is unbounded. The proof for the discrete case is the same.

I assume there are easier proofs like using L'Hospital rule, etc.

Comment: I need to prove it by definition.
sorry if was not clear enough

Comment: Then I think Hee Kwon Lee's proof is better. You can learn from his.